# Ferrite Beads Design

Tags: ferrite-bead

Currently learning about ferrite beads.

I have noticed that on the data sheets they have graphs of impeadance vs frequency.

to ensure you have the best ferrite for the job I assume you want to get the greatest impeadance at the frequency you are experiencing the noise.

Can anyone confirm why having a greater impeadance is better?

Thanks 
SS

Comment: Do you understand what impedance is and can tell it in your own words?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that having a greater impedance at noise frequency is better. Impedance is like a barrier preventing noise from entering your system: the higher it is, the better.

Answer (score 8):

In this context, you can (sort of) think of a ferrite bead as being a frequency-variable resistor.  The higher the frequency, the higher the resistance.

A resistor by itself doesn't attenuate anything, but does with a load following it.  *Something* will be on the output side of the ferrite bead, and this something will have some input impedance.  The ferrite bead impedance and this input impedance together form a voltage divider.  Note that the higher the ferrite bead impedance, the more the signal is attenuated.